# Doom(?) Emacs: whitespace-mode uses incorrect style in c-mode?

Tags: doom, whitespace, whitespace-mode

I'd like emacs to display tab-marks nicely in c mode: here's an example of how it displays tabs in my config.el, which is how I want it to display tabs everywhere.

[image]

You can see the nice `>` characters in the middle few lines.

Doom's not configured to display tab marks in c-mode, weirdly. That can be fixed with the following snippet.

```
(use-package whitespace
  :custom
  (whitespace-style '(face indentation tab-mark))

  ;; Turn on global-whitespace-mode, otherwise doom-highlight-non-default-indentation-h sets its own
  ;; whitespace configuration for some reason.
  :config (global-whitespace-mode +1))
```

Even with that though, it's kind of ugly.

[image]

It looks like the faces are messed up for some reason? Is this how tab marks look for everyone in c-mode or is doom messing some faces up? Is there some variable that I can `M-x debug-on-variable-change` to see if it's getting messed up?

Comment: This looks like a face issue. `whitespace` uses a couple different faces to render its text, place your cursor on the problematic character and invoke `describe-face` to see what face is used.